# img.height() and img.width() returning 0 in chrome,but returns correct value in mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have an image field in my **markup**.I am setting its source using **jquery**. I need its height and width. for that I have used **image.height()** and **image.width()** methods. it works proper in **mozilla** but not in **chrome**, I have tried **image.height** and **image.width** method, but not getting any value. also I have tried by changing **prop** method to **attr** for setting the image **src**, but it is also gives me the same result. I am pasting my code here.

**html**

```
<div>
<img src class="my-image"/>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var img = $(".my-image");
imageWidth = $('.my-image').width();
        imageHeight = $('my-image').height();
        alert(imageHeight);
});
```

what is the error here ? any help is appreciated

Comment: You have to wait for the image to load.

Comment: `$("my-image")` to `$(".my-image")`. And Where is your `$('.product-image-og-size')` ?

Comment: @RLam sorry ! copy paste error, edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is the image is not yet loaded on `$(document).ready();` and at that point the element has dimensions of `0px` by `0px`. In order to ensure your image is loaded use the `$(window).load();` event instead of document ready.

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
    var img = $(".my-image"),
        imageWidth = $('.product-image-og-size').width(),
        imageHeight = $('img.product-image-og-size').height();
        alert(imageHeight);
});
```

Comment: @ShajeerAhmd you can check both here. https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7145/ and https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7144/

Comment: Deprecated for a while, it's `$(window).on('load' ...` these days.